# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file '/var/www/html/new_7alaqa/public/dumpfiles/15869372079790_1036teachernote.txt'

Tags: mysql, laravel, ubuntu

Folder /var/www/html/new_7alaqa/public/dumpfiles/ owned by mysql:mysql and i'm trying to run:

```
$note_file= time().$user_idd."_".$halaqa_idd.$typed."note.txt";
$note_query="select * from notes where is_deleted = 0 and halaqa_id=".$halaqa_idd."  into outfile '/var/www/html/new_7alaqa/public/dumpfiles/$note_file' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '),\n(';";

DB::select($note_query);
```

[image: folder permission]

***Edit:*** 
from mysql commands: 
working in /tmp  directory and default directory

```
select * from users  into outfile '/var/www/html/new_7alaqa/public/dumpfiles/11.txt';
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/var/www/html/new_7alaqa/public/dumpfiles/11.txt' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
mysql> select * from users  into outfile '/tmp/11.txt';
Query OK, 1417 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Can you see giving write permissions to www-data?

Comment: no, @SanthoshJ I will google it, can you give me the way ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server/db/user accounts set up, here are some things to try:

1. Try changing the owner of `dumpfiles` to `www-data`:

```sh
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data dumpfiles
```

You can revert by running

```sh
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql dumpfiles
```

2. Give `FILE` permission to your MySQL user.

```sql
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO user;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

It's important to note that even if you already gave your user all permissions by running `GRANT ALL`, it doesn't include the `FILE` permission.

3. Try escaping the path:

```php
$dumpFilePath = addslashes('/var/www/html/new_7alaqa/public/dumpfiles/$note_file');
$note_query="select * from notes where is_deleted = 0 and halaqa_id=".$halaqa_idd."  into outfile '$dumpFilePath' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '),\n(';";
```

Comment: I tried the first one and same error, the second MySQL gives me an error[ ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table]

Comment: For the second one - did you substitute your user name where it says "user"?

Comment: trying [GRANT FILE ON *.*  root@localhost] gives 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
also, third solutions didn't solve  the problem

Comment: also from MySQL user table, this user takes all privileges

Comment: Did you type "GRANT FILE ON . root@localhost" or "GRANT FILE ON *.* root@localhost"? Also did you run "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"?

Comment: "GRANT FILE ON . root@localhost" or "GRANT FILE ON . root@localhost"both are the same

Comment: here what i run :
mysql> GRANT FILE ON *.* TO root;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)